# accessing a groupby column value

Tags: pandas, group-by, resampling

If I have used the groupby function in pandas (on LOC) along with resample to for example obtain daily mean pressure and flow values at some venue. Is there any way to access a value in the groupby column, LOC, by index or some other method, so that I can use it for the title of a plot. In other words can I get access to 'venue1'. I had to use groupby to even get the venue column in the resampled dataframe since resample doesn't appear to bring through any non-numeric fields

```html
                      date         flow (l/s)   pressure(m)  count    year        day
LOC                                                                      
venue1             2018-01-01    7.683219     40.914583      1     2018      Monday
venue1             2018-01-02    7.780802     39.117708      2     2018      Tuesday
venue1             2018-01-03    7.770167     41.407292      3     2018      Wednesday
```

I'd appreciate any insights on this

Comment: Why do you need groupby to access one row, can't you do that directly? Unless you mean you want to access the Nth row in every group?

Comment: probably inexperience. I have several files that I process into data frames from which I want to generate plots. I am trying to loop through them all and in that loop. I also want to generate a plot for each location of for example average pressure by day. Each df, of course, has a different venue so I want to access that to use it in creating a title for each plot

Answer (score 1):

If you know which group you need beforehand, you can use `get_group` on the `GroupBy` object:

`df.groupby("LOC").get_group("venue1")`

This returns all rows of the original dataframe belonging to that group and all its column values can be accessed as with ordinary `DataFrame` objects.